# Java: GridBagConstraints - best way to pad components

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

So I'm working on a GridBagLayout UI right now. I'm trying to space my components out just right, and in all my research I've found four different tools that seem to affect the spacing between components and their overall positioning. I'm just seeking clarity on the best way to use each of these. I may be new at Java, but I'm very OCD about having finite control over my layouts, so I'm trying to figure out how to fine tune component positioning.

I understand the syntax for all of these, just looking for advice on how to use them properly. I also understand that once they're declared, they affect every component that follows them in the code until they are "reset" by declaring them again.

weight(x,y) - this one I'm having a real hard time understanding it's actual effect. Does it add padding before or after the cell? Or does it just move around the contents in the cell?

ipad(x,y) - seems to add padding only after the object in the cell (to the right/bottom). Is that correct?

insets - seems to be a great, precise tool for this. Are there rules that govern when it is appropriate to use it? Best practices, etc?

anchor - ties a component to the top/bottom/left/right/center of the cell. Mostly interested how this method interacts with the others I listed here. How does where the component is anchored affect the padding generated by the three methods above.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Maybe the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will help since it has explanations for each of the constraints and a demo program to play with. Also, you never need to just use one layout manager. Nesting panels with different layout managers can be helpful.

Comment: I've been looking at that, I'll take another look. Been tinkering with this panel so long my head is spinning a bit. Also I am definitely nesting panels, maybe I should've just pasted my code instead of asking a concept question. I've got one panel with extra space on top that I'm trying to get rid of, and I keep tweaking the values of all four of those items, mixing and matching, and even eliminating entirely. Nothing seems to fix it.

The weirdest part is this panel is nearly identical to another panel I have that doesn't have the same problem...

Comment: `maybe I should've just pasted my code instead of asking a concept question.` - I rarely use GridBagLayout, but I have a better chance of helping if I see code rather than trying to guess what your problem is by a verbal description. There are so many combinations of contraints that we can't possibly guess what you are doing. This posted code is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (or `MCVE`) and should be included with every question.

Comment: you are absolutely right, and from now on I will definitely employ that best practice.

I believe I've discovered my problem: the "super panel" (for lack of a better description) that this panel is in uses a gridlayout, which locks everything to the same size. Gonna start experimenting with changing that to something that varies a bit more, hopefully that'll resolve the extra space issue. That explains why none of those methods seemed to be working properly